# C# DateTime Convert from string to DateTime in differents TimeZones

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm struggling with a problem. i have a string date looks like this, "2015-05-02 01:00:00", extracted from a database.

I know that it's british time, but my local time is belgian time.
I'm trying to store the date in UTC and in (CEST or CET depend of the season), converting it from the British time i've extract.

I tried to set Kind property to British time, but the result seems to be in local or utc time. So, i can do half of the job, but not the rest (e.g. I still need the CEST/CET time).

I tried to use this :

```
string dateString = (string) line["stringDate"];

DateTime ukTime = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("en-GB", false));
DateTime belgianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(ukTime, "Romance Standard Time");
```

The result is the same for both ukTime and belgianTime: 2015-05-02 01:00:00 with kind = unspecified.

It should be 2015-05-02 02:00:00 for belgianTime

Comment: Just waiting for Jon Skeet to show up to recommend using Joda :-)

Comment: Have you tried `ukTime.ToLocalTime()`?

Comment: I tried in a fiddle & given this result in `belgianTime`: `2015/5/2 3:00:00`. If I used `ToLocalTime` it has same result as `ukTime`.

Comment: @derape wouldn't it be Noda for C#? Isn't Joda for Java?

Comment: @DannyGoodall ahh right! I got mixed up

Comment: @Pikoh, & Tetsuya Yamamoto, i tried it, and the time still show 2015-05-02 01:00:00, but someone who delete his post propose that i can just add 1 hours to the british time to get the belgian one, and it seem to be a solution, not sure if it's 100% exact.

Comment: `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dt, "GMT Standard Time", "W. Europe Standard time");` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add the source time zone to the conversion method it gives the desired answer, even without specifying the `IFormatProvider`.

```
string dateString = (string) line["stringDate"];

DateTime ukTime = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
DateTime belgianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(ukTime,
    "GMT Standard Time",
    "Romance Standard Time");
```

This gives time `Kind == Unspecified`. However if you use:

```
var belgianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(ukTime,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"), 
    TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

for the conversion, you get `Kind == Local`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line of code.

```
var time = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        var clientZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
        var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(time, clientZone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `ConvertTime` method. [ConvertTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx)

a quick sample -

```
string s = "2015-05-02 01:00:00";

var dt = new DateTime(2015, 05, 02, 1, 0, 0);

var t = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"), 
                     TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time"));
```